# Suicide squad movie prequel?

Tags: dc-extended-universe, sequels, suicide-squad

Wasn't there a movie with characters similar to the ones in suicide squad a few years ago? It seems like a sequel, especially the harley quinn character.

Answer (score 6):

Wouldn't have been a movie.  The upcoming Suicide Squad film [will be Harley Quinn's silver screen debut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harley_Quinn#Film).  Could be possible you are thinking of the first [Lego Batman film](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lego_Batman:_The_Movie_%E2%80%93_DC_Super_Heroes_Unite#Cast), which does have Harley Quinn and a couple other Suicide Squad characters in it.

A couple other possibilities are [Batman: Assault on Arkham](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman:_Assault_on_Arkham) and [Batman Beyond: Return of the Joker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman_Beyond:_Return_of_the_Joker).

That said, all the above are animated/direct-to-tv movies, so unless you remember that aspect, I'm doubting this is what you're thinking of.